# Copy table data to another sheet by using column header

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I want to copy data from certain columns in a table to another worksheet by using the column header names rather than column numbers.
If the first column is named "ID", refer to this column as Range("ID") rather than Range("A").

```vb
Sub Program()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lRow As Long
    Dim table As ListObject
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WeeklyData")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MonthlyData")
    Set table = ws1.ListObjects.Item("WeeklyTable")
   
    'Find first empty row where values should be pasted in MonthlyData sheet
    With Worksheets("MonthlyData")
        j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
   
    'Find last row of data in WeeklyData sheet
    lRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Only copy data if WeeklyData sheet has data
    If lRow > 1 Then
        With ws1
             table.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange.Copy Destination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues=ws2.range("A" & j)
        End With
    End If
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Please first compile your code in Excel (paste it into a module, then select *Debug > Compile VBAProject*), and after that update your post with the "fixed" version.  There's no point in us looking at code that doesn't compile.  For example variable names in VBA cannot start with a digit, and every variable needs a Type unless you want it to be a Variant.

Comment: Compiled! I got a syntax error for the line "table.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange.Copy Destination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues=ws2.range("A" & j)", which I don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to transfer values you can do that directly without copy/paste:

```vb
Sub Program()
   
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lRow As Long
   Dim table As ListObject, j As Long
   
   Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WeeklyData")
   Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MonthlyData")
   Set table = ws1.ListObjects.Item("WeeklyTable")
   
   'Find first empty row where values should be pasted in MonthlyData sheet
   With Worksheets("MonthlyData")
        j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row + 1
   End With
   
   'Only copy data if WeeklyData sheet has data
   If Application.CountA(table.DataBodyRange) > 0 Then
     CopyValues table.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange, ws2.Range("A" & j)
     '...other columns here
   End If
   
End Sub

'copy values from `rngSrc` to `rngDest`
Sub CopyValues(rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range)
    rngDest.Cells(1).Resize(rngSrc.Rows.Count, _
                            rngSrc.Columns.Count).Value = rngSrc.Value
End Sub
```